# WCF Service: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, dll

I Created a **WCF Service** and added a **dll file as a reference** and i am **getting the error** mentioned in the title during runtime.

Created a **WPF application** and added the **same dll** file as a reference but **it worked**.

The dll file has other references that i added manually in the bin/debug folder of the wpf app.

When i try to do the same for WCF service it is not working.

Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Can you provide more detail ? Which Assembly ?

Comment: The Assembly is used within our organisation. It's a actually proxy that talks to a server. It depends on Omni related dlls.

Comment: Are **all** the necessary assemblies in the bin folder of the WCF service where it is deployed?   Just because the references are in your local solution/project doesn't guarantee they'll be on the server/destination (depending on what they are and how you deploy).

Comment: @Tim Yeah.Exactly man. Thats what i dont know which is the deployment folder. I think its using Visual studio development server. I tried searching but i didnt find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to C#. Unfortunately no one answered it, i found solution myself after three hours :(.

**A dll file will always be used by an exe file**.

In this case the exe was in the folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft** **shared\DevServer\10.0** which is the folder for ASP.NET development server.

So the dependent dll files need to be copied there. Copying to the bin folder will not work.